# it is possible to use a system property to specify cluster url in ehcache 3

Tags: xml, properties, cluster-computing, terracotta, ehcache-3

It is possible to use a system property in ehcache3.xml when configuring the cluster url? 
like:

```
<terracotta:connection url="${ehcache.cluster.server}" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not possible as-is because there is an XSD validation on that field, which prevents the value from starting with such characters.

However, you can trick that XSD validation by doing the following:

```
<terracotta:connection url="terracotta://${ehcache.cluster.server}" />
```

and make sure to not have the `terracotta://` in your system prop value.